# Angular JS with Laravel 5.3 search filter issue

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am developing a search filter using angular js and laravel 5.3.

My Angular JS:

```
    $scope.search = function() {

    var url = "bssrfilter1";

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $.param($scope.bssrfilter),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        $scope.bssrfilter = response;

    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
    });
}
```

My Laravel Controller:

```
 public function filter(Request $request)
{       
    $search = $request->searchkey;

    return $bssr = DB::table('adv')
        ->where('adv.description','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('adv.advtopic','like','%'.$search.'%')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
}
```

My laravel route:

```
 Route::post('/bssrfilter1', 'SiteController@filter');
```

When I submit the form for the first time it gives me correct search results. But after results are once displayed, submitting the search form again does not filter results. Any solution would be of great help.

Comment: what is the value of this $.param($scope.bssrfilter) ?

Comment: This has the parameter submitted from the form which is passed to $search = $request->searchkey in the laravel controller. It looks like this in the blade: <input type="text" name="searchkey" ng-model="bssrfilter.searchkey"/>

Comment: <form name="frmFilter" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="search()" novalidate="">
   
 Keyword
 <input type="text" id="search" name="searchkey" ng-model="bssrfilter.searchkey" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>   
   
     </form>

Comment: It looks like the subsequent form submission after the first one has empty value in searchkey even though i enter some keyword in it. I am just confused why.